# How can I make Python's console display a specific type of Unicode characters (Tifinagh characters) ? And would that also apply to the TkInter?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, character-encoding, special-characters

I would like to know the simplest way to make Python's console display a certain type of Unicode characters (Tifinagh) instead of having them displayed as question marks framed within a rectangular box, and if that would be possible on the tkinter too ?

Contrarily to Python's console Thonny has the ability to display them correctly within its own console.

I would like to add that as soon as I switch the encoding of my script from Utf-8 to Latin-1, the script becomes unusable. Python can't interpret it anymore.

P.S.: I'm on Python 3.6.4.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by "Python's console"? Running Python in your terminal? If so, what OS and what terminal? Or do you mean the terminal that comes with IDLE?

Comment: I'm on Windows 10 x64, Python 3.6.4, and by console I indeed meant Terminal : ) . Thank your for your interest in my question.

Comment: have you tried simply configuring your console to have a font that supports the characters you want to see?

Comment: No I unfortunately didn't do that, is there a specific thread for this operation ? And would it also work for tkinter ?